# More trouble with facebook connect login (JS SDK)

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I'm really not understanding this at all.  My goal is to not have a bunch of js in my main aspx file.  I want it in an external file.  I simply cannot make it work.

The following *seems* to be working (got the login popup), but it never updates the "guest" thing and the login button stays there.  Console says "FB is not defined", so obviously it has no idea waht FB.api means... sorry I suck at this :|

**[-----index.aspx----------------]**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="index.aspx.vb" Inherits="MyGameEngineBeta.index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Scott's Test</title>
        <script src="JS/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script src="JS/facebook.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
        <div>Welcome <span id="guest" class="UserNameWelcome">Guest</span><span id="name" class="UserNameWelcome"></span>!</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**[-----facebook.js----------------]**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'mysiteid', // App ID
        channelURL: '//www.mysite.net/channel.html', // Channel File
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        oauth: true, // enable OAuth 2.0
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
    alert('Facebook initialized');
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
} (document));

//update guest/username if logged in or not
FB.api('/me', function (user) {
    if (user != null) {
        alert('logged in');
        var name = document.getElementById('name');
        name.innerHTML = user.name
        $('#guest').hide();
    } else {
        alert('guest');
        $('#image').hide();
        $('#name').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the call to FB.init inside the window.fbAsyncInit handler, which is good, that way it won't get executed until all the FB stuff is loaded. But you have the call to FB.api outside of the handler, meaning you have no guaranty that all.js has finished loading before the call to FB.api takes place. The simplest solution would be to just move the FB.api block inside the window.fbAsyncInit function just after the alert.